# Did Pennywise use the boat as bait?

Tags: it, it-2017

I just watched the 2017 version of IT. And something that's been on my mind since watching it is, did Pennywise use the boat as a lure to get Georgie? I know he used it to get Georgie to reach into the sewer, but did he "control" the boat to land into the sewer or was it just coincidence?

Answer (score 3):

I always understood the original movie(haven't seen the new one) that Pennywise did in fact use the boat-the music and atmosphere seemed to indicate that there was something bad about to happen. He couldn't just snatch Georgie right off the street!